# Mantel Test data assumptions

Tags: r, matrix, distance-functions, cochran-mantel-haenszel

Does the Mantel Test works with non-normal distributed samples? I couldn't find anything clear enough about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no assumption about normality at all for the Mantel test. The Mantel test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantel_test) is a test of correlation between two matrices and so there are some restrictions on the form of the matrices that are necessary.  For example, the matrices need to be of the same rank.